# String matching implementation

Tags: c++, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I wrote the below code to check whether a certin string exists in a text or no. The issue is that `match()` function always returns `false` even the pattern exists in the text.

```
int main(){

    char *text="hello my name is plapla";
    char *patt="my";

    cout<<match(patt,text);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool match(char* patt,char* text){

    int textLoc=0, pattLoc=0, textStart=0;
    while(textLoc <= (int) strlen(text) && pattLoc <= (int)strlen(patt)){
        if( *(patt+pattLoc) == *(text+textLoc) ){
            textLoc= textLoc+1;
            pattLoc= pattLoc+1;

        }

        else{
            textStart=textStart+1;
            textLoc=textStart;
            pattLoc=0;
        }

    }
    if(pattLoc > (int) strlen(patt))
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string`? Any particular reason or just love for c?

Comment: Instead of `*(patt+pattLoc)` you can use `patt[pattLoc]`, but since you love parts of C, I think `textLoc` should rather be a `char *`.

Comment: Maybe this was homework or coding practice.

Comment: @Adban Wait, so you actually _like pointers and raw memory management_?

Comment: You're _really_ going to want to move the `strlen`s outside of the loop, or hope your compiler is smart.

Comment: Why are you casting strlen()?

Comment: This is the standard C++ function `std::match`.  There's no reason to write it yourself.  Otherwise, there's a serious lack of `const`, multiple calls to `strlen` on the same string, `x = x + 1` instead of the idiomatic `++ x`, and `if (cond) return true else return false;`, rather than simply `return cond;`.  It's as if you went out of your way to make it slow and unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pattLoc < (int)strlen(patt)` in your `while` loop.
Loop will stop when `pattLoc == 2`, so you avoid comparing the `'\0'` of `"my"` with the `' '` of `"hello my name is pala"`, which set `pattloc` to `0` and `return false`.

Or better, use string `substr`.

Comment: `string::substr` is likely to have even worse performance than his multiple calls to `strlen` (although it's far from sure).  For better or for worse, the C++ library is designed around iterators.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is:

```
bool
match( std::string const& pattern, std::string const& text )
{
    return std::search( text.begin(), text.end(), 
                        pattern.begin(), pattern.end() )
            != text.end();
}
```

This is idiomatic C++, and the way I would expect any C++ programmer to
write it, at least in a professional environment.

If the goal is to learn how to write such a function, then of course, 
the above isn't much of a solution.  The solution then should be mroe
divide and conquer; there's much too much in `match` for you to put it
in one function.  I'd recommend something like:

```
bool
startsWith( std::string::const_iterator begin,
            std::string::const_iterator end,
            std::string const& pattern )
{
    return end - begin >= pattern.size()
        && std::equal( pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), begin );
}

bool
match( std::string const& pattern, std::string const& text )
{
    std::string::const_iterator current = text.begin();
    while ( current != text.end()
            && !startsWith( begin, text.end(), pattern ) ) {
        ++ current;
    }
    return current != text.end();
}
```

This can obviously be improved; for example, there's no point in
continuing in the while loop when the length of the remaining text is
less than the length of the pattern.

And if your professor insists on your using `char const*` (if he insists
on `char*`, then he's totally incompetent, and should be fired), this
can easily be rewritten to do so: just replace all calls to `begin` with
the pointer, and all calls to `end` with `pointer + strlen(pointer)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem:

`while(textLoc <= (int) strlen(text) && pattLoc <= (int)strlen(patt))`

should be:

`while(textLoc < (int) strlen(text) && pattLoc < (int)strlen(patt))`

and 
`if(pattLoc > (int) strlen(patt))`
to
`if(pattLoc >= (int) strlen(patt))`